# update user data php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to update some data and it returns fine but in my data base nothing is changing:

```
<?php
function updater($value, $id){

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli( 'localhost' , 'webjgb_updter' , 'upDat3r*' ,'webjgb_updtst' );

$value =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value);
$id =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$id);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}   
$sql = "UPDATE editinplace SET nombre='{$value}', apellidos='{$value}', email='{$value}', telefono='{$value}' WHERE id='{$id}'";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
}   

if(isset($_POST['nombre']))
    updater($_POST['nombre'],$_POST['id'])
?>
```

Comment: is this upDat3r* your password with the * at the end ? do you get any error message ? or blank page ?

Comment: is $value defined somewhere else. so that the function can get the $value-variable ?

Answer (score 0):

That may be because the IF is not executed:

```
if(isset($_POST['nombre']))
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one error where the `if-clause` does nothing. it's just there:

```
if(isset($_POST['nombre']))
 updater($_POST['nombre'],$_POST['id'])
```

change it to:

```
                            ↓
if(isset($_POST['nombre'])) {
     updater($_POST['nombre'],$_POST['id']) }
                                            ↑
```

and i've changed `'{$value}'` to `'".$value."'`
and here is the corrected script:

```
<?php
function updater($value, $id){

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli( 'localhost' , 'webjgb_updter' , 'upDat3r*' ,'webjgb_updtst' );

    $value =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value);
    $id =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$id);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }   

    $sql = "UPDATE editinplace SET nombre='".$value."', apellidos='".$value."', email='".$value."', telefono='".$value."' WHERE id=".$id."";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } 
    else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
}   

if(isset($_POST['nombre'])) {
    updater($_POST['nombre'],$_POST['id'])
}
?>
```